# Installing Google Drive API in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse

I am having trouble trying to install the api's needed to interact with Google Drive in Eclipse. I have downloaded the zip file

google-api-java-client-1.11.0-beta.zip

from the google website but it has little instruction on what to do with it after downloading. I looked through the readme but it did not help me accomplish anything.

I have also installed the Google Plugin but that does not appear to have helped as I am still receiving errors when trying to use sample code provided by google.

The errors that I am receiving are related to these import statements:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
```

With the error being that the import cannot be resolved.

Any instruction where to place/install the downloaded API's or on how to resolve the import issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take care of the Drive-related imports, you'll need a few jars from the Google Drive SDK. There are a few large ones, so you may want to add them individually to suit your app.

If that doesn't resolve the com.google.android.gms.* imports, the Google Play Services add-on needs to be installed (from Extras -> Google Play Services in the SDK Manager) and google-play-services.jar needs to be added to your build path.

In this case, the following jars were needed:

1. google-api-services-drive-v2-rev1-1.7.2-beta.jar
2. google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
3. google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
4. google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar
5. google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
6. google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar

Download above jar from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs) except google-api-services-drive-v2-rev1-1.7.2-beta.jar

To use google-api-services-drive-v2-rev1-1.7.2-beta.jar first you need to install Google play service

[Use this imports as here in your activity](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android#step_1_generate_the_signing_certificate_fingerprint_sha1)

Comment: please help me tell me about JacksonFactory()??

Comment: i found error at this line JacksonFactory()??JacksonFactory jf = new JacksonFactory();                            // You need a JSON parser to help you out with the API response
        Credential credential = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setAccessToken(accountName);
        HttpRequestFactory rf = ht.createRequestFactory(credential);
        Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(ht, jf, null);
        b.setJsoHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {

Comment: @JellyBean would you please describe your query?